# Browser doesn't ask for mic permission

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, browser

I want the browser to ask for permission to use the mic.
It askes for permission on PC but doesn't on mobile.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})

            .then(stream => {
                var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
                mediaRecorder.start()
                var mediaChunks = []
                mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable",function (e) {
                    
                    mediaChunks.push(e.data)
                })

                mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop",function () {
                    var mediaBlob = new Blob(mediaChunks)
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaBlob)
                    var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO")
                    audio.src = url
                    audio.controls = true
                    //audio.classList.add("ay")
                    audio.setAttribute('id','ay')
                    big.appendChild(audio)

                })

                setTimeout(function() {
                    mediaRecorder.stop()
                    alert("stopped")
                },3000)
            })
```

Comment: I think the cause for this can be that you are allowing to use microphone for the browser within phone settings. I did try this code using the phone and I was asked if I want to allow the use of  microphone from the browser.

Comment: Is it possible that the mobile device browser already has permission to use the microphone, so it doesn't need to ask again?

Comment: Morpheus can you tell me where did you try it bec I tried it and it didn't ask